# nodejs variable in regex match()

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

how can I use a variable in match() if I want to use regex?
This works fine for me:

```
if (message.match('!' + cmd)) {
  this.client.say(to, myJson[cmd]);
}
```

but if I try something like this it will not check the variable.

```
    if (message.match(/!cmd/i)) {
      this.client.say(to, myJson[cmd]);
    }
```

I already searched for a solution but could only find something for replace.

Edit: it's not a duplicate of [How do you use a variable in a regular expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/494035/how-do-you-pass-a-variable-to-a-regular-expression-javascript) as it explains it for replace not match.

Comment: Found a solution now with `message.match(new RegExp('^!' + cmd, 'i'))`